# Bind with 1 call of copy ctor

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, bind

I need deferred call of some function with arguments. Have next test code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

struct test
{
    test()
    {
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    test& operator=(test const& t)
    {
        std::cout << "operator=" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    test(test const& t)
    {
        std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~test()
    {
        std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int foo(test const & t)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    test t;
    boost::function<int()> f = boost::bind(foo, t);
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
dtor
copy ctor
dtor
dtor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

So we can see what copy ctor called 11 times!!!

Ok. Change boost::bind to std::bind:

```
int main()
{
    test t;
    boost::function<int()> f = std::bind(foo, t);
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
dtor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

Copy ctor called 9 times. Ok. If change boost::function to std::function copy ctor will be called 4 times only. But it is bad behavior too.

Is it possible do this with 1 call of copy ctor? std::ref is a bad idea, because of it can invoke in other thread and etc.

Sorry for my bad English :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda expression.

```
int main()
{
    test t;
    std::function<int()> f = [=](){ foo(t); };
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Binding is exceedingly redundant due to the incredible ease etc of using lambdas. In addition, you did compile in Release mode with all optimizations on, right?

You won't get only one copy constructor call, because first you have to produce a function object, and then assign that function object into the std::function. Maybe it could be `std::move`'d?

Since you don't have lambdas and even binding produces three copies, you're just going to have to manually write your own function object in this case.

Comment: Yes, Release mode and -O2. std::move is possible in some cases.

Comment: In MinGW with GCC 4.4 I have error: expected primary-expression before '[' token on std::function<int()> f = [=](){ foo(t); }; :(

Comment: GCC 4.4 doesn't support lambdas, but you tagged C++0x so I expected that you had lambda support.

Answer (score 1):

Using lambdas is a good answer.  If for whatever reason that doesn't work for you, another possibility is storing the result of the bind in something other than a std::function:

```
decltype(std::bind(foo, t)) f = std::bind(foo, t);
```

or:

```
auto f = std::bind(foo, t);
```

On my system (clang/libc++) this outputs:

```
ctor
copy ctor
dtor
dtor
```

Though your milage may vary.

Comment: Hm, with MinGW (gcc version 4.4.0 (GCC)) it has 3 calls of copy ctor :(

Answer (score 0):

It does depend a bit on the lifetime of the object that you want to bind.

Assuming that that object's lifetime includes the lifetime of the functor, just do

```
int main()
{
    test t;
    boost::function<int()> f( boost::bind(foo, boost::ref( t ) ) );
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Yields one constructor call and one destructor call. :-)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: He already said that he can't use a reference because it's multi-threaded.

Comment: @DeadMG: I didn't notice, *but*, the called function takes argument by ref to `const`, so, no tread safety problem (well, unless one is added by modifying original object, but then just make *one* copy).

Comment: @Alf: Except `t` is allocated locally, making a reference to it in a multi-threaded program a death sentence.

Comment: @DeadMG: no, I did address the lifetime issue. second para. :-)

Comment: @Alf: But he already stated that is *not* the lifetime. Assumptions are great- if the OP didn't already explicitly state otherwise.

Comment: @DeadMG: It's trivial to adjust the lifetime. Instead of "assuming", read it as "make sure". :-) I can't see the statement you're referring to  --  but a thread that accesses things after `main` would be a dangerous design, and a quite different (orthogonal) issue.